# Why does indexing a HashMap not return a reference?

Tags: indexing, rust, hashmap

I am writing the follwing test code.

```
fn test() {
    let mut m = HashMap::new();
    m.insert("aaa".to_string(), "bbb".to_string());

    let a = m["aaa"];   // error [E0507] cannot move out of index of `HashMap<String, String>`
    let a  = m.index("aaa");  // ok, the type of a is &String. I think The compile will add & to m;
    let a :&String = (&m).index("aaa");  // ok, the type of a is &String.
    println!("{:?}", m["aaa"]);  // ok
}
```

I am not understand why the return type of `m["aaa"]` is `String`, not `&String`. Because the [index(&self, key: &Q) -> &V](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.index) of the trait `Index` has a `&self` parameter, I think the compile will add a `&` to m, and the return type of m["aaa"] should be &String, so String "bbb" will not be moved out of m.

If the compile does not add & to m, it will not find the index() method, the error should be like `m cannot be indexed by "bbb"`;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the docs for `Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Index.html):

> `container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)`

So what happens is that when you write `m["aaa"]`, the compiler is actually *adding* a `*` that dereferences the value returned by [`Index::index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index), whereas when you call `m.index ("aaa")`, you get the `&String` reference directly.

As pointed out by @user4815162342, programmers are supposed to make their intent explicit by writing either `&m["aaa"]` or `m["aaa"].clone()`.

Moreover `println!("{:?}", m["aaa"]);` works because the `println!` macro does add a `&` to all the values it accesses¹ to prevent accidental moves caused by display, and this cancels out the `*` added by the compiler.

---

(1) This is indirectly documented in the docs for the [`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/fmt/index.html#format_args) macro.

Comment: Probably also wotrh mentioning: 1) the intended way to write the assignment is `let a = &m["aaa"]` or `let a = m["aaa"].clone()` depending on the intent. 2) `println!()` works because it cheats and automatically borrows its arguments to prevent moves as consequence of display.